# How to change table and column name in mongodb springboot application?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to change the name of collection and corresponding columns in mongodb-springboot application.
My entity class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_profile_id")
    private Long userProfileId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}
```

My Repository class is:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user_profile")
public interface UserProfileRepository extends MongoRepository<UserProfile, Long> {
...
}
```

But the collection created is **userProfile** instead of **user_profile**. Also, there is an **_id** filed instead of **user_profile_id** in the collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the [@Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Document.html) annotation on the POJO class.

Comment: Thanks Prasad. And for column names?

Comment: Just browse thru this documentation and you will find some examples; [Spring Data MongoDB Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/).

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `@Document` in place of `@Entity` in case of MongoDB.
use `@Document(collection = "User_detail")` to name table.